# QuickSort NullPointerException Problem : Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, quicksort

My quicksorting algorithm seems like it should all be in order and work just fine, but I'm getting a NPE when I try to sort a list of random ints. What exactly am I doing wrong??

```
public ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> list, int l, int r){
        ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(l<r){
            int partVal = partition(list, l, r, 0);
            sortedList = quickSort(list, l, partVal-1);
            sortedList = quickSort(list, partVal+1, r);
        } 

        return sortedList;
    }

    public int partition(ArrayList<Integer> list, int l, int r, int pivot){
        int pivotVal = list.get(pivot);

        swapElements(list, pivot, r);

        int counter = l;

        for(int i = l; i < r; i++){
            int pos = list.get(i);
            if(pos <= pivotVal){
                swapElements(list, i, counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        swapElements(list, r, counter);

        return counter;
    }

    public void swapElements(ArrayList<Integer> list, int a, int b){
        int temp = list.get(a);
        list.replace(a, list.get(b));
        list.replace(b, temp);
    }
```

Comment: "What exactly am I doing wrong??" You're not posting the stacktrace

Comment: That isn't even a quicksort. There are at least three errors in your code.

Comment: see my comments in the answer below, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this:

```
while (l < r) {
    int partVal = partition(list, l, r, 0);
    sortedList = quickSort(list, l, partVal-1);
    sortedList = quickSort(list, partVal+1, r);
}
```

How are you expecting the loop to ever terminate? The values of `l` and `r` don't change, so the condition isn't going to become false.

It's not clear why you're looping at all... the point is that the recursive call does the work. I suspect you want an `if` here instead. You've said in a comment that you then end up with a `NullPointerException`, which you should give details of. Step through your code carefully, working out what you expect it to do and what it's actually doing.

Comment: Thank you for all of the responses, everyone. I got it working, with a combination of feedback from Jon and ratchet freak. :) Thanks yet again, StackOverflow. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are sorting the array inplace no need to return a new list

```
public ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> list, int l, int r){
    if(r<l)return list;
    int partVal = partition(list, l, r, l);
    quickSort(list, l, partVal-1);
    quickSort(list, partVal+1, r);

    return list;
}
```